# Fragment onCreateView - android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I was working on my application and it was perfectly working on my phone.

But when I published it on google play store, my customer had an ANR when he installed it on his phone.

So I checked the stack trace on the google play console.

Title

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
```

Type `android.view.InflateException`

```
    android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:640)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:750)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:813)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:511)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:415)
  at com.imajdroid.sechaba.Login.onCreateView (Login.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.isInitialized (Fragment.java)
  or                     .performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  or                     .set (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  or                     .set (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  or                     .set (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView (FragmentStateManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run (FragmentManager.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6934)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:288)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:614)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:750)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:813)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:511)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:415)
  at com.imajdroid.sechaba.Login.onCreateView (Login.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.isInitialized (Fragment.java)
  or                     .performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  or                     .set (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  or                     .set (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  or                     .set (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView (FragmentStateManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run (FragmentManager.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6934)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:4017)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:3929)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:3779)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:776)
  at android.view.View.<init> (View.java:4001)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java:513)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java:509)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java:505)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init> (ConstraintLayout.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:288)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:614)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:750)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:813)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:511)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:415)
  at com.imajdroid.sechaba.Login.onCreateView (Login.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.isInitialized (Fragment.java)
  or                     .performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  or                     .set (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  or                     .set (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  or                     .set (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView (FragmentStateManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run (FragmentManager.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6934)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I use Navigation component. and the issue was in the "onCreateView" method.

Comment: You're getting a `Resources$NotFoundException` while some `ConstraintLayout` in `Login` is trying to load a drawable (maybe for a background?). Are you sure that all of your drawables are available for every API level that you support? For example, do you possibly have a drawable only under `res/drawable-v24/`, but your customer is running on a version below that?

Comment: Yes, I actually do.
I will fix it now, Thank you.